# Reinitialize search after first round of results

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, input

In my code I have an `input` field with a 'Clear' button and a 'Search' button.

The Clear button removes the counters, empties the input field, remove highlights and hides showed collapsed items but does not reinitialize the search.

The problem is that I need to check if the input value is the same as before, otherwise I should start a new search.

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // console.log(occurrences);

  $(document).on("click", "#findWord", function(e) {
    let occurrences = [];
    e.preventDefault();
    // clear();
    let x = document.querySelector("#searchedWord").value;
    let error = document.querySelector("#message");
    
    if (x == "") {    
      error.style.display = "block";
      error.style.color = "red";
    } else {
      error.style.display = "none";
      highlightWord();
      displayOcc();
    }
    
    // let clickInput = document.querySelector('#searchedWord');
    let clickClear = document.querySelector("#clear");

    // Make clear button to appear on input field click
    // clickInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    //     clickClear.style.display = 'block';
    // });

    clickClear.addEventListener("click", clear);

    function clear() {
      // get the search term from the input
      let clickInput = document.querySelector("#searchedWord");
      clickInput.value = "";
      var spans = $(".reports-list-item__title--compendium > mark");
      // console.log(spans);
      spans.each(function() {
        spans.contents().unwrap();
      });
      occurrences.splice(0, occurrences.length);
      // reset our labels
      $("#count").html("");
      $("#current").html("");
      $(".timeline-compendium__content").collapse("hide");
      $(".timeline-type .timeline-type__content").collapse("hide");
    }

    function highlightWord() {
      // create a regex from our term
      const word = document.getElementById("searchedWord").value;
      const r = new RegExp("(" + word + ")", "ig");
      $(".reports-list-item__title--compendium").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).text().match(r)) {
          // console.log($(this).text().match(r));
          // get all the matches
          var matches = $(this).text().match(r);
          // console.log(matches);
          // loop through them
          $.each(matches, function() {
            // push the index of this section onto the array
            occurrences.push(i);
            // console.log(occurrences);
          });
          // wrap each found search term with our `found` span to highlight it
          $(this).html($(this).text().replace(r, "<mark>$&</mark>"));
          $(this).closest(".timeline-compendium__content").collapse("show");
          // scroll to highlighted word(s)
          // $(this).closest(".timeline-compendium__content")[0].scrollIntoView();
          $(this).closest('.timeline-type .timeline-type__content').collapse('show');
        }
      });


    }

    function displayOcc() {
      let lengthOccurrences = occurrences.length;
      console.log('Length (number) of occurrences is:' + ' ' + lengthOccurrences);

      let currViewMatch = Number(document.querySelector("#current").textContent);
      console.log('Number of current viewed match is:' + ' ' + currViewMatch);

      // if we are currently viewing a match, increment so we move to the next one
      currViewMatch = currViewMatch > 0 ? currViewMatch + 1 : 0;
      // if the incremented number is higher than the number of matches, reset it to 0
      currViewMatch = currViewMatch > lengthOccurrences ? 1 : currViewMatch;
      // if this is the first click and we found matches, set current to the first match
      currViewMatch = currViewMatch == 0 && lengthOccurrences > 0 ? 1 : currViewMatch;

      let insertNbrOcc = lengthOccurrences > 0 ? " of " + lengthOccurrences : " matches found";
      // // set number of matches found
      let count = document.querySelector("#count");
      count.textContent = insertNbrOcc;

      // // set  number of currently viewed match
      let nbrViewMatch = document.querySelector("#current");
      nbrViewMatch.textContent = currViewMatch;
    }
  });
  
  $("#btnNext").click(test);
  
  var i = 0;

  function test() {
    var pickHighlights = document.querySelectorAll("mark");
    var viewportOffset = pickHighlights[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    // these are relative to the viewport
    var top = viewportOffset.top;
    window.scrollTo(0, top);

    i++;
    if (i >= pickHighlights.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.found {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#labels {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.timeline-compendium {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.timeline-type__header {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(46, 177, 100);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.timeline-type__header:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(35, 119, 70);
}

#tab-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input#findWord {
  background-color: rgb(248, 211, 3);
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#clear {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 150px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#message {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#btnNext {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

mark {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

.stickyBar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row stickyBar">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-2">
      <div id="searchForm" class="d-flex flex-column">
        <label for="searchedWord">Search... </label>
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 d-flex ">
          <input type="text" id="searchedWord" placeholder="Search..." aria-labelledby="searchedWord" value="cool" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
          <button type="submit" id="findWord" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          <input type="button" id="btnNext" value="next" />
          <div id="clear" role="button">X</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div id="labels">
        <span id="current"></span>
        <span id="count"></span>
        <small role="alert" id="message" aria-hidden="true">Please enter a word to start searching</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <section class="timeline-compendium">
        <a class="btn timeline-compendium__header" data-toggle="collapse" href="#introduction" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="introduction">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">1<sup>st</sup> collapsible item</div>
            <div class="col"><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true" data-original-title="Collapse/expand"></em>
              <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="timeline-compendium__content collapse" id="introduction">
          <div class="timeline-type">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#foreword" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="foreword">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="timeline-type__header timeline-type__header--title">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-auto timeline-type__chapter">1</div>
                      <div class="col timeline-type__title">First nested collapsible</div>
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em>
                        <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="timeline-type__content collapse" id="foreword">
              <ul class="reports-list">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">First cool</div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
      <!-- section 2 -->
      <section class="timeline-compendium">
        <a class="btn timeline-compendium__header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#titleA" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="titleA">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">2<sup>nd</sup></div>
            <div class="col"><span>collapsible item</span></div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true" data-original-title="Collapse/expand"></em>
              <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="timeline-compendium__content collapse" id="titleA">
          <div class="timeline-type">
            <a class="accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#summary" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="summary" class="collapsed">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="timeline-type__header timeline-type__header--title">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-auto timeline-type__chapter">2</div>
                      <div class="col timeline-type__title">Second nested collapsible</div>
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em>
                        <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="timeline-type__content collapse" id="summary">
              <ul class="reports-list">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">Second cool</div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
      <!-- section 3 -->
      <section class="timeline-compendium">
        <a class="btn timeline-compendium__header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#titleB" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="titleB">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">3<sup>rd</sup></div>
            <div class="col"><span>collapsible item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto"><em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em><span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span></div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <div class="timeline-compendium__content collapse" id="titleB">
          <div class="timeline-type">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#chapterB0" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="chapterB0" class="collapsed">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="timeline-type__header timeline-type__header--title">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-auto timeline-type__chapter">3</div>
                      <div class="col timeline-type__title">Third nested collapsible</div>
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em>
                        <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="timeline-type__content collapse" id="chapterB0">
              <ul class="reports-list">
                <li>
                  <a class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--nolink">No link</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">
                      Some content with link cool
                    </div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">
                      Some content with link
                    </div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-type">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#chapterB2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="chapterB2" class="collapsed">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="timeline-type__header timeline-type__header--title">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-auto timeline-type__chapter">4</div>
                      <div class="col timeline-type__title">Fourth nested collapsible
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em>
                        <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="timeline-type__content collapse" id="chapterB2">
              <ul class="reports-list">
                <li>
                  <a class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--nolink">No link</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">
                      Some content with link
                    </div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the old mark and reset the i index when you click the Search button in the click handler of findword button. I added the code below.

```js
   //clear old marks
    var spans = $(".reports-list-item__title--compendium > mark");
    // console.log(spans);
    spans.each(function () {
      spans.contents().unwrap();
    });
    
    //reset i
    i = 0;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // console.log(occurrences);
  var i = 0;
  
  $(document).on("click", "#findWord", function (e) {
    let occurrences = [];
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //clear old marks
    var spans = $(".reports-list-item__title--compendium > mark");
    // console.log(spans);
    spans.each(function () {
      spans.contents().unwrap();
    });
    
    //reset i
    i = 0;

    let x = document.querySelector("#searchedWord").value;
    let error = document.querySelector("#message");

    if (x == "") {
      error.style.display = "block";
      error.style.color = "red";
    } else {
      error.style.display = "none";
      highlightWord();
      displayOcc();
    }

    // let clickInput = document.querySelector('#searchedWord');
    let clickClear = document.querySelector("#clear");

    // Make clear button to appear on input field click
    // clickInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    //     clickClear.style.display = 'block';
    // });

    clickClear.addEventListener("click", clear);

    function clear() {
      // get the search term from the input
      let clickInput = document.querySelector("#searchedWord");
      clickInput.value = "";
      var spans = $(".reports-list-item__title--compendium > mark");
      // console.log(spans);
      spans.each(function () {
        spans.contents().unwrap();
      });
      occurrences.splice(0, occurrences.length);
      // reset our labels
      $("#count").html("");
      $("#current").html("");
      $(".timeline-compendium__content").collapse("hide");
      $(".timeline-type .timeline-type__content").collapse("hide");
    }

    function highlightWord() {
      // create a regex from our term
      const word = document.getElementById("searchedWord").value;
      const r = new RegExp("(" + word + ")", "ig");
      $(".reports-list-item__title--compendium").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).text().match(r)) {
          // console.log($(this).text().match(r));
          // get all the matches
          var matches = $(this).text().match(r);
          // console.log(matches);
          // loop through them
          $.each(matches, function () {
            // push the index of this section onto the array
            occurrences.push(i);
            // console.log(occurrences);
          });
          // wrap each found search term with our `found` span to highlight it
          $(this).html($(this).text().replace(r, "<mark>$&</mark>"));
          $(this).closest(".timeline-compendium__content").collapse("show");
          // scroll to highlighted word(s)
          // $(this).closest(".timeline-compendium__content")[0].scrollIntoView();
          $(this)
            .closest(".timeline-type .timeline-type__content")
            .collapse("show");
        }
      });
    }

    function displayOcc() {
      let lengthOccurrences = occurrences.length;
      console.log(
        "Length (number) of occurrences is:" + " " + lengthOccurrences
      );

      let currViewMatch = Number(
        document.querySelector("#current").textContent
      );
      console.log("Number of current viewed match is:" + " " + currViewMatch);

      // if we are currently viewing a match, increment so we move to the next one
      currViewMatch = currViewMatch > 0 ? currViewMatch + 1 : 0;
      // if the incremented number is higher than the number of matches, reset it to 0
      currViewMatch = currViewMatch > lengthOccurrences ? 1 : currViewMatch;
      // if this is the first click and we found matches, set current to the first match
      currViewMatch =
        currViewMatch == 0 && lengthOccurrences > 0 ? 1 : currViewMatch;

      let insertNbrOcc =
        lengthOccurrences > 0 ? " of " + lengthOccurrences : " matches found";
      // // set number of matches found
      let count = document.querySelector("#count");
      count.textContent = insertNbrOcc;

      // // set  number of currently viewed match
      let nbrViewMatch = document.querySelector("#current");
      nbrViewMatch.textContent = currViewMatch;
    }
  });

  $("#btnNext").click(test);
  

  function test() {
    console.log(i);
    var pickHighlights = document.querySelectorAll("mark");
    var viewportOffset = pickHighlights[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    // these are relative to the viewport
    var top = viewportOffset.top;
    window.scrollTo(0, top);

    i++;
    if (i >= pickHighlights.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.found {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#labels {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.timeline-compendium {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.timeline-type__header {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(46, 177, 100);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.timeline-type__header:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(35, 119, 70);
}

#tab-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input#findWord {
  background-color: rgb(248, 211, 3);
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#clear {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 150px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#message {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#btnNext {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

mark {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

.stickyBar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row stickyBar">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-2">
      <div id="searchForm" class="d-flex flex-column">
        <label for="searchedWord">Search... </label>
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 d-flex ">
          <input type="text" id="searchedWord" placeholder="Search..." aria-labelledby="searchedWord" value="cool" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
          <button type="submit" id="findWord" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          <input type="button" id="btnNext" value="next" />
          <div id="clear" role="button">X</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div id="labels">
        <span id="current"></span>
        <span id="count"></span>
        <small role="alert" id="message" aria-hidden="true">Please enter a word to start searching</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <section class="timeline-compendium">
        <a class="btn timeline-compendium__header" data-toggle="collapse" href="#introduction" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="introduction">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">1<sup>st</sup> collapsible item</div>
            <div class="col"><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true" data-original-title="Collapse/expand"></em>
              <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="timeline-compendium__content collapse" id="introduction">
          <div class="timeline-type">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#foreword" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="foreword">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="timeline-type__header timeline-type__header--title">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-auto timeline-type__chapter">1</div>
                      <div class="col timeline-type__title">First nested collapsible</div>
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em>
                        <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="timeline-type__content collapse" id="foreword">
              <ul class="reports-list">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">First cool</div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
      <!-- section 2 -->
      <section class="timeline-compendium">
        <a class="btn timeline-compendium__header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#titleA" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="titleA">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">2<sup>nd</sup></div>
            <div class="col"><span>collapsible item</span></div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true" data-original-title="Collapse/expand"></em>
              <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="timeline-compendium__content collapse" id="titleA">
          <div class="timeline-type">
            <a class="accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#summary" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="summary" class="collapsed">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="timeline-type__header timeline-type__header--title">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-auto timeline-type__chapter">2</div>
                      <div class="col timeline-type__title">Second nested collapsible</div>
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em>
                        <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="timeline-type__content collapse" id="summary">
              <ul class="reports-list">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">Second cool</div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
      <!-- section 3 -->
      <section class="timeline-compendium">
        <a class="btn timeline-compendium__header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#titleB" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="titleB">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">3<sup>rd</sup></div>
            <div class="col"><span>collapsible item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto"><em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em><span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span></div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <div class="timeline-compendium__content collapse" id="titleB">
          <div class="timeline-type">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#chapterB0" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="chapterB0" class="collapsed">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="timeline-type__header timeline-type__header--title">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-auto timeline-type__chapter">3</div>
                      <div class="col timeline-type__title">Third nested collapsible</div>
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em>
                        <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="timeline-type__content collapse" id="chapterB0">
              <ul class="reports-list">
                <li>
                  <a class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--nolink">No link</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">
                      Some content with link cool
                    </div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">
                      Some content with link
                    </div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-type">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#chapterB2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="chapterB2" class="collapsed">
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="timeline-type__header timeline-type__header--title">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-auto timeline-type__chapter">4</div>
                      <div class="col timeline-type__title">Fourth nested collapsible
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <em class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse/expand" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em>
                        <span class="sr-only">Collapse/expand this item</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="timeline-type__content collapse" id="chapterB2">
              <ul class="reports-list">
                <li>
                  <a class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--nolink">No link</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="reports-list-item reports-list-item--compendium">
                    <div class="col-auto reports-list-item__title reports-list-item__title--compendium">
                      Some content with link
                    </div>
                    <div class="reports-list-item__url"><em class="icon-url" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Link" data-delay="400" aria-hidden="true"></em></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're one of kind! "Helping someone else through difficulty is where civilization starts". Thank you very much!

Comment: @onweb, Thankyou. I am happy to help.